# REPLACE() for several values and use the results IN()

Tags: mysql, string

I want to do something like that

```
SELECT
    id,
    num
FROM
    sometable
WHERE
    num IN (REPLACE ('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''));
```

but:

```
(REPLACE ('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''))
```

returns: **'123, 456, 678'**,

not as I expected: **'123', '456', '678'**

So, is it possible to make list of elements after REPLACE() for use that results as an arguments IN()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(num, replace(replace('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''), ', ', ',') ) > 0
```

Comment: If i correctly understand find_in_set() this function must return position if find match. 
`code` SELECT FIND_IN_SET(123, REPLACE(REPLACE('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''), ', ', ''))
nothing returned
`code` SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''), ', ', '')
return
123456678 is it correct?

Comment: Oops, the intention is to replace `', '` with `','`.

Comment: `code`SELECT FIND_IN_SET(123, REPLACE(REPLACE('K-123, K-456, K-678', 'K-', ''), ', ', ','))
return nothing

Comment: @Initialis . . . I'm not sure what you mean.  That statement returns "1" in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/49355), so it seems to work.

Comment: sorry, my fault. Did not notice the obvious.